# Azure Function: Local Development: How to load intermediate certficiate which chains to root certificate?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

How can you load a non self signed certificate when developing azure functions locally. I am using the .NET runtime and am able to successfully make requests after creating a self signed certificate and setting the `commandLineArgs` in the `launchSettings.json` to:
`--cors * port 7005 --useHttps --cert \"certificate.pfx\" --password \\\"password\\\""`
over HTTPS using postman. However, an IOT device I am working with requires the HTTPS server to have a valid chain of trust.

How I tried to solve the issue:

Contents of file named device.ext:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = device
```

1. Create CA key `openssl genrsa -des3 -out root.key 2048`
2. Create CA cert `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key root.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out root.pem`
3. Create server key `openssl genrsa -out device.key 2048`
4. Create server signing request `openssl req -new -key device.key -out device.csr`
5. Create server cert `openssl x509 -req -in device.csr -CA root.pem -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile device.ext`
6. Create pfx file `certutil -mergepfx device.crt certificate.pfx`

When trying to run the azure functions with commandLineArgs: `--cors * port 7005 --useHttps --cert \"certificate.pfx\" --password \\\"password\\\""`

I get the error:
`The specified network password is not correct`

Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated I've been banging my head on this will for 8 hours. Thx for any help!!!